# Lenar un JTable con JPA

Tags: java, java-swing, hibernate, jpa

Soy novel en esto de **JPA** y no se casi nada sobre el, a pesar de que he investigado un poco, aún no encuentro la forma de llenar la tabla con los datos de la **`Entity`**, el código con el que hago un **DefaultTableModel** e intento llenar la tabla con este es el siguiente:

```
public JTable listarTabla(JTable tabla) {
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    tabla.setModel(modelo);

    tabla = new javax.swing.JTable() {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    Object[] columnas = new Object[3];

    modelo.addColumn("NOMBRE");
    modelo.addColumn("APELLIDO");
    modelo.addColumn("MOVIL");

    int objetos = agendaJPA.extraerTodos().size();

    for (int i = 0; i < objetos; i++) {
        columnas[0] = this.agendaJPA.extraerTodos().get(i).getNombre();
        columnas[1] = this.agendaJPA.extraerTodos().get(i).getApellido();
        columnas[2] = this.agendaJPA.extraerTodos().get(i).getMovil();

        modelo.addColumn(columnas);
    }

    return tabla;
}
```

El método **`extraerTodos()`** que utilizo para llenar la tabla es este:

```
public class AgendaJPADAOImpl implements AgendaJPADAO, Serializable {

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AGENDAJPAPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

 public List<Contacto> extraerTodos() {
    List<Contacto> contactos;
    contactos = em.createNamedQuery("AgendaJPA.getAll").getResultList();

    return contactos;
    }
}
```

A su vez, el método **`extraerTodos()`** hace referencia al nombre de este código **JPQL** dentro del **POJO**

```
package comm.agendaJPA.modelo;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;

@Entity(name = "ContactoAgenda")
@Table(name = "contacto")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "AgendaJPA.getAll", query = "SELECT c FROM ContactoAgenda c")
})
public class Contacto implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "fecha")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar fecha;
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
@Column(name = "apellido")
private String apellido;
@Column(name = "movil")
private Integer movil;

public Contacto() {
}

public Contacto(String nombre, String apellido, int movil, int casa, String personal, String trabajo, String direccion) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.movil = movil;
    this.casa = casa;
    this.personal = personal;
    this.trabajo = trabajo;
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Calendar getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Calendar fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public Integer getMovil() {
    return movil;
}

public void setMovil(Integer movil) {
    this.movil = movil;
}
```

Al correr el programa obtengo estos resultados:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Divide los problemas en partes... por una parte está extraer los datos de la BD mediante JPA (al JPA no le importa un comino si los datos se van a mostrar por GUI, usar para calcular un valor, imprimir en una impresora, etc.), por otra parte esta representar los datos mediante el GUI (al GUI no le importa un comino si los datos viene de JPA, de JDBC, de un servidor web...)

Comment: Y, por lo que más quieras, no repitas la consulta a BD ¡3 veces por iteración! Si al salir del trabajo alguien ha pinchado las ruedas de tu coche, seguro que ha sido el DBA.

Comment: @SJuan76 jajajjaj, lo que entiendo por lo que me quieres decir es que cree un método para extraer los datos y otro para mostrar la tabla, además porque me trae todas esas columnas, si solo especifico 3 y a pesar de esto los datos siguen sin mostrarse

Comment: Básicamente, por una parte pruebas el código JPA (aunque sea imprimiendo los datos por consola) y por otra el código de la UI (aunque sea pasándole una lista de `Contacto` que has rellenado "a mano"). Y, con una sola llamada a "extraerTodos" sacas todo el contenido de la tabla de una vez y ya lo tienes en memoria, no es necesario repetir la llamada tantas veces porque la consulta de BD es lenta (y además, ni siquiera tienes la garantía de que en cada consulta te devuelva los datos en el mismo orden).

Comment: Con modelo `addColumn` estás añadiendo columnas... y lo estás haciendo para cada registro; cada registro se muestra como una **fila**

Comment: Entiendo, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo este ejemplo como mapear una `tabla` en `JPA`
**CLASE ROL**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rol")

public class Rol implements 
Serializable {

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "descripcion")
private String descripcion;

public Rol() {
}

public Rol(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Rol(Integer id, String descripcion) {
    this.id = id;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

}




public void modeloTabla() {
    List<Rol> listado = listarTodos();
    /*coloco el nombre de las  columnas de la tabla Rol a el modelo */
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null, new Object[]{"ID", "DESCRIPCION"});
    for (Rol r : listado) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{r.getId(), r.getDescripcion()});
    }
    /*establecemos el modelo  al Jtable llamado jTabla*/
    jTabla.setModel(model);
}




 public List<Rol> listarTodos() {
    List<Rol> datos;
    /*la unidad de persistencia del archivo Persistence.xml se llama unidadPersistencia*/
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unidadPersistencia");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Rol r");
    datos = q.getResultList();
    return datos;
}
```